# Go-gorm mysql "unsupported type []string, a slice of string"

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I use gorm, and try to create transaction to mysql. I have a struct

```
type Game struct {
    Images []string
}

game := Game{Images: []string{"1.png", "2.png"}}

db := Database()

tx := db.Begin()

if err := tx.Create(&game).Error; err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    return errors.New("Cannot add game")
}

tx.Commit()
```

But I get error `(sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []string, a slice of string)`. I understand, that mysql unsupported this type, but can I someway resolve this problem? I guess I can change type to `json.rawMessage`, but I think it's a wrong way.

I use dialect `"github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"`

Comment: You can store it in a `string` that contains JSON encoded data, and marshal/unmarshal it as you write/read from the DB. However, the reason why this type isn't supported is because MySQL isn't supposed to be used like that. You should have an image table with a game ID in it and a path string or something like that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a list of something in MySql, you have two options

1. You could serialize the list yourself (into a comma-separated string, json, or another serialization format) and store it in a string or bytes column.
2. You can use join to associate the two tables.

gorm supports joins through something it calls associations. In this case, you have a has many association (http://doc.gorm.io/associations.html#has-many).

An example of how you might do this is:

```
type Game struct {
    gorm.Model
    GameImages   []GameImage
}

type GameImage struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}

db.Model(&game).Related(&gameImages)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datatypes.JSON` as your type

```
import "gorm.io/datatypes"

type Game struct {
     Images datatypes.JSON `json:"images"`
}
```

reference: https://github.com/go-gorm/datatypes